# How can I resolve the "no such host" error on App Engine when it attempts to perform a DNS lookup on a domain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I wrote this golang program to perform a GET request to an internal website, in order to aggregate the results and compile information into a health checks dashboard. The code runs locally and it was able to perform dns lookup on the internal URL but when I deployed the code to AppEngine it runs into dns lookup and no host error. What can I do to fix that issue? Thank you!

Comment: Please add more detail on what you have set up. How is the internal website's network set up? To allow App Engine to connect to an instance in a VPC, typically you need to use [Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/connecting-vpc). The more details you provide, the better the answer.

Comment: @JuliaNguyen Did John Hanley's comment help you to resolve your issue?. can you add the details so it will be helpful to troubleshoot the issue.